# My Female Cat bites my new kitten's neck and drags them

Tags: cats

I have a female cat that is 2-3 years now, she was supposed to be a mother-cat but her kittens sadly died due to them not being able to develop properly.

Just recently I got a new kitten from an adoption center, I'm still unsure if its a girl or a boy but my female cat would constantly hiss or paw the new kitten's face.

As of today, I came home and I saw my female cat licking my new kitten. I found it cute when I saw this, but I found it even more cute when my female cat started biting the new kitten's neck as an attempt to carry the new kitten, but I feel bad for the new kitten because he's meowing loudly like its hurting him.

Should I seperate them? or just leave it be?

Comment: Maybe of interest: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/15795/is-it-normal-for-a-cat-to-display-maternal-behavior-while-not-being-the-mother

Comment: Remember to distinguish between bite, nip, and grab. It sounds like this case is "grab".

Answer (score 0):

Remember, scruff of the neck is a standard way for cats to move kittens, and they're pretty careful about it. The complaints may be nothing but "hey, sis, I was busy doing something else!"